# How to look back in time(weekly) using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I have a table in which there are two columns containing week & year (both int). I want to create a function that looks  26 weeks back from a reference point (it could have been user-provided week-year or the latest week-year in the table). By looking back, I mean I can filter out the data that is farther away than 26-week gap.

What I have done so far is to make a timestamp of week & year by adding a constant day :

```
df['wk_yr'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + "-" + df['Week'].astype(str)+"-"+str(1)
df['date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['wk_yr'],format = '%Y-%W-%w')
```

The idea is to use this timestamp to look back in time, however, this doesn't work when we have 53 weeks in  year, e.g. 2020 had the 53rd Week, and when applied the code 53-2020 turn out to be the same as 1-2021, which really is not the case

Can there be any other approach to it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal agreement on what "week number" means.  There are some businesses for which 2020 week 53 IS the same as 2021 week 1.  I think you'll have to supply your own business rule.